# How to return a database dump as a download

Tags: php, postgresql

I am working on a function for a PostgreSQL database, that when client issues a database dump, the dump is offered as a download. This snapshot could then later be used to restore the database with. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it. When the user presses the button, an AJAX call to the server is made, as to which the server executes the following code:

```
if($_POST['command'] == 'dump'){
    $dump = $table->Dump();
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=/"'.$dump.'/"');
}
```

Where `$table->Dump()` looks like this:

```
public function Dump(){
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__)."/db_Dump.out";
    exec("pg_dump ".$this->name." > $filename");
    return $filename;
}
```

The dump isn't made though. Any tips on this?

This approach however, doesn't work. I thought that setting the headers would be enough to cause a download, but apparently I was wrong. So what would be the correct way of creating a download?

---

**Edit 1**, @stevevls:

```
if($_POST['command'] == 'dump'){
    $dump = $table->Dump();
    $fh = fopen($dump, 'r') or die("Can't open file");
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=/"'.$dump.'/"');
    $dumpData = fread($fh, filesize($fh));
    fclose($fh);
    echo $dumpData;
}
```

I still don't get anything as a download though.

---

**Edit 2**, @myself

I have been able to get a return value, it seemed that the the check if the command given was 'dump' was never reached. I fixed that, and now I get an error on the pg_dump command. I now get

```
sh: cannot create ../database/db_Dump.sql: Permission denied
```

I bet this is due to php not being allowed to run pg_dump, but how could I get the system to allow it to be able to run it?

---

**Edit 3**, @myself

After resolving the issue with the pg__dump (I added www-data, Apaches user on my system, to the sudoers list, which resoved the issue. Also setting the correct permissions on the directory to write to is handy aswell.) I now get the db_Dump.sql as plain text instead of a save as dialog. Any ideas on that?

Comment: are you shure that your www user can perform `pg_dump`?

Comment: Yes, it is a system admin function though, so not every user is able to do so...

Comment: so if you create an empty php file and call this `exec(` there will be the dump?

Comment: where's the code that reads the dump file and writes it to the wire?

Comment: A good point stevevls... It's not there yet.. >.<

Comment: Break it up in little pieces. Strip all other things and just do the `exec()`, and see if the file is made. If it is, add the `fread()` to return the file contents to the web browser. If that works, add the Content-headers. Finally, add the POST-check. It'll become a lot clearer when it goes wrong.

Comment: I've done that already, the dump isn't made as well... I am going to check into that in a bit. On a second note, I've tried to just offer a text file as a download, to which I echo a single string. This doesn't execute as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it was all due to the fact of how I requested the download. It seems that it is impossible to get a download when you request it via Ajax, as the returned file get's accepted in the success method of the call. After Changing this to a direct link to the file, I was able to get a download.

Answer (score 1):

first of all check if dump file was created on disc.

Second, check if your PHP script has not reached time limit, because making dump can last long.

Third, you want to read whole dump into memory? You can easly reach memory limit, so do it part-by-part. On php.net you have example in [fread manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php):

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: The whole file being read into memory at once is just a test setup with a limited database (about 30-40 entries). I doubt that will fill up memory. But I guess it is fair to say that it still is a good tip to keep in mind.